# Is there standard file names for Terms of Use / Privacy Policy?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, privacy

Are there standard file names for Terms of Use and Privacy Policies?

For some reason, I remember that Internet Explorer and possibly other browsers used to look for them on the current website, and display a little warning icon...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for [P3P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P3P)?

> The privacy policy can be retrieved as
>   an XML file or can be included, in
>   compact form, in the HTTP header. The
>   location of the XML policy file that
>   applies to a given document can be:
>
> 1. specified in the HTTP header of the document
> 2. specified in the HTML head of the document
> 3. if none of the above is specified, **the well-known location
>      /w3c/p3p.xml** is used (for a similar
>      location compare /favicon.ico)